# Help me decipher this output

Tags: ruby

I have started learning Ruby recently and I was trying out the following piece of code.

```
a=[1,2]
b='slam dunk'
a.each { |b| c=a*b; puts c;}
```

I am getting the following output. I have no clue why. I expected an error or something to be thrown. Can someone explain me why this happens?

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't do ruby but I'm guessing it's implicit conversion logic ... what happens if you change a to slamdunk and b to [1,2] ?

Comment: I tried to do that change, I'm getting an error **can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)**

Comment: You may want to do `puts c.inspect` rather than `puts c` so that you can see better what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will try to explain the output you're seeing.

In ruby if we have an array e.g. `[1, 2]` and multiply it by a number *n* then you get the array repeated *n* times e.g.

```
irb(main):012:0> [1,2] * 2
=> [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

So your `each` loop prints `[1, 2] * 1` followed by `[1, 2] * 2`

If you are asking why having `b` assigned to a string and then assigned to a number doesn't generate an error then this is not a problem in dynamically typed languages like ruby. e.g.

```
irb(main):017:0> a = 5
=> 5
irb(main):018:0> a = 'no problem'
=> "no problem"
```

After your each loop `b` will just have the last value it had in the loop i.e. 2

Answer (score 4):

The block variable b overwrites "slam dunk", so what happens is

```
c=[1,2]*1 # => [1,2]
c=[1,2]*2 # => [1,2,1,2]
```

This is what you see in the output

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating the each the variable b that was originally assigned the value is hidden by the b argument to the block.

So what the each loop actually receives on each pass is

```
 [1,2] * 1 #1st Pass
 [1,2] * 2 #2nd Pass
```

So the 1st pass prints 1 2 and the 2nd pass prints 1 2 1 2 (i.e. it prints the array twice)

Answer (score 0):

I think outer b has no effect inside loop.
On the first cycle you print your array once.
On the second cycle your print your array two times